# Python is saying a function isnt getting enough arguments when ive checked that it is

Tags: python

I'm building a vm translator to translate vm commands and there is a function saying it is not getting enough arguments. I added a print statement before the function is called and the arguments are there.

The function in question is as follows

```
    def generate_assembly_command_list(command_object):
        intermediate_list = []
        for x in command_object:
            for j in range(len(command_object[x])):
                intermediate_list.append(VmWriter.generate_assembly_command(command_object[x][j], x))
        return intermediate_list
```

The function is called by the VmWriter's init method

```
def __init__(self, command_object):
        self.assembly_command_list = VmWriter.generate_assembly_command_list(command_object)
```

The VmWriter is instantiated in the run method of the VmTranslator

```
def run(self):
        parser_instance = Parser(self.is_file, self.file_or_directory)
        vm_writer_instance = VmWriter(parser_instance.command_object)
```

The Function takes in a dictionary whose keys are strings of vm file names with the values being a list of strings that represent vm commands. It then goes through each string in every key's list creating a corresponding assembly command then appends it to intermediate_list.
I have have added a print statement above the append command to print command_object[x][j] and x which properly prints a vm command string and the vm file name respectively.

Error output:

```
  File "/home/tyler/scripts/HackCompiler/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    vm_translator_instance.run()
  File "/home/tyler/scripts/HackCompiler/vm_translator/vm_translator.py", line 15, in run
    vm_writer_instance = VmWriter(parser_instance.command_object)
  File "/home/tyler/scripts/HackCompiler/vm_translator/vm_writer.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.assembly_command_list = VmWriter.generate_assembly_command_list(command_object)
  File "/home/tyler/scripts/HackCompiler/vm_translator/vm_writer.py", line 26, in generate_assembly_command_list
    intermediate_list.append(VmWriter.generate_assembly_command(command_object[x][j], file_name))
```

I am at a complete loss as to why this is not working. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Share the caller code as well. Share full error details as well

Comment: You probably want to add @staticmethod (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) to `generate_assembly_command_list` and generate_assembly_command`, otherwise they will expect a first argument of type VmWriter (the first argument in a function within a class is always the class instance unless you add @staticmethod or @classmethod).

Comment: You are calling a class-method as if it was static